# Call method in an object of previous operator in lambda expression

Tags: lambda, java-8, stream, rx-java

I have piece of code

```
client.confirmPayment(identity, entity.getId())
                .map(response -> response.id)
                .flatMap(itemId -> signingService.orderSigning(itemId, identity))
                .doOnSuccess(signatureOrder->signatureOrder.setRedirectUrl("XXXX"));
```

the `client.confirmPayment` method returns stream of type `Response`

```
class Response{
    private String id;
    private String url;
}
```

Is there any way to call `response.url` from the `doOnSuccess` operator ?

Comment: Just an idea to build upon - `map` it into a `SimpleEntry` of `Id, Response`... use the id as currently and use the `Response` later on.

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like this:

```
Single<Response> responseSingle = client.confirmPayment(identity, entity.getId())
    .flatMap(response -> Single.just(response)
        .flatMap(r -> signingService.orderSigning(r.id, identity))
        .doOnSuccess(order -> order.setRedirectUrl(response.url))
    );
```